# How to solve $\sqrt{3}x-\cos 2x=0$ for sketching the graph of $y=\sqrt{3}x-\cos 2x$?

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the following question.

> $$\begin{align}
> \\\sqrt{3}x-\cos 2x=0\\
> \end{align}$$

I have no idea how to solve the above question with x inside and outside the cos.
[image]
Since I have to sketch the graph of the (1)equation[0, $\pi $], if I do not know the value of x when y=0, I cannot sketch it properly.

How can I deal with this problem?

***Thank you for your attention.***

Comment: How? Numerically, I suppose.

Comment: Maybe $\sqrt{3}\sin x-\cos 2x=0$ or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newton's method looks like it will work here.
Start with a rough answer: $x_0 = 0.5$
After that, $x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)/f\,'(x_n)$

Answer (score 2):

The solutions to $\cos x = ax$ do not in general have nice closed-form expressions as functions of $a$.

So unless $a=\sqrt3$ is somehow an exceptional case (which doesn't look likely), the best you can do is to approximate the solution numerically, such as with Newton's method as Michael suggests.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael said, use Newton's method. Since your function is well behaved, start for example at x=0. The first iterate will be 0.57735, the next 0.410054, the next 0.40126, the next 0.40123 and so on